# Avoid memory leak in C++ class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, unordered-map, delete-operator

I've defined a C++ class with the following header file:

```
class EarleyParser
{

    public:

        EarleyParser();
        virtual ~EarleyParser();

        void initialize( string filePath, bool probabilityParse );

    private:

        bool probabilityParser;

        typedef unordered_map< string, list<Production>* > productionHashTable;
        productionHashTable earlyHashTable;

};
```

As you can see a member element of the class is an [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/) whose key element is a string and content element is a pointer to a list of objects of another class named `Production` (don't mind it, it could be anything).

My question is if I should leave it to the default destructor to free memory allocated, or if I should manually inspect the hash table and delete all of its elements.

In the second case what would be the procedure? Calling this for each element will be ok?

```
EarleyParser::productionHashTable::const_iterator got = this->earlyHashTable.find( "key" );
delete[] got->second;
```

Comment: If this object is owning this list, than you should delete it there.
Use shared pointer instead of a raw pointer to a list - then it will delete itself.

Comment: *if I should leave it to the default constructor to free memory allocated* - surely you mean destructor?

Comment: @Component10 - of course...thks for pointing out...

Comment: @Wojciech - can you be a little more specific plz?thks...

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: Shouldn't it be EarlyParser or is Earley a proper noun that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Benj - I think it's [`Earley`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser)

Comment: forget about new and delete, and you'll solve lots of problems :)

Comment: @BЈовић - can you please provide a proof to your statements...it would be wonderful ;D

Comment: @Matteo smart pointers do pretty much exactly what you would do with `new` and `delete`, except better.

Comment: Sorry, little correction. If you can forget about raw pointers, and you'll solve lots of problems (as Cubic and other people suggested).

Comment: Have you considered using an [`unordered_multimap<string, Production>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)?

Comment: @LucTouraille - For collisions I intend that multiple values can have the same key. I'll give a look to the multi_map..thks for pointing out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clarify who owns the `list<Production>` objects owned by `EarlyParser`. If `EarlyParser` owns them, then you need to free the resources. You can do it by iterating over the list and calling `delete` on each dereferenced iterator (**not** `delete[]`). Or you can store `unique_ptr<list<Production>>` instead. On the other hand, the simplest solution is to store `list<Production>` unless you really have very strong reasons for storing pointers.

Comment: From a container point of view what will be the difference between storing the entire list as second element or a pointer to the list?Is there at all?thks...

Comment: @Matteo the first difference is that you don't have to worry about memory management. The second is that if you do stuff like copying the container, all the lists will be copied, which is more than just copying pointers. Also, container ops that require copying the elements *could* be more expensive. In C++11 this is done with move semantics, which is quite cheap.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So, since I do not expect to copy the container I should probably simply store the list as second element. This way I also avoid the memory leak problem, since destroying the `EarleyParser` class with standard destuctor will call the standard destructor of map (which will destory the list). Have I got it right?thks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to store pointers to anything in your map, you'll have to manually go through the map and delete each one. Normally in a class  you'd stick to RAII (Resource Acquisition is Initialization) and construct things in the *constructor* and destroy in the *destructor*

```
 for (;;)
     delete map->second; //it's not an array of lists
```

**However a pointer to a container is NOT a good idea**.  Why do you do need a pointer? What problem are you trying to solve using a pointer to a `list`?

Using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` is a much better idea than raw pointers. Raw pointers should be a last resort, not the first thing you grab when you can't think of anything better.

Comment: I'll have collisions in my `unordered_map`, so I wanted a way to access all elements that collided. I thought it was better to store a pointer as second element rather than putting an entire list. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: If you want to use a pointer, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` but don't use raw pointers.

Comment: In some answers below they suggested to store the entire list as content of the `unordered_map`. Do you think it would be a better approach?

Comment: @Matteo: When you say there will be collisions, are you talking about multiple values having the same key, or multiple keys having the same hash? The latter is the usual meaning of the term "collision", and is handled internally by `unordered_map`. If you mean that multiple values can be associated with the same key, than perhaps you could use an [`unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap).

Answer (score 2):

Use a:

```
typedef unordered_map< string, std::unique_ptr<list<Production> > > productionHashTable;
```

instead. Then you don't need to worry about managing memory.

Comment: In your opinion what would be the better solution between using the `unique_ptr`, or storing the full list as second element of the map?thks for help..

Comment: @Matteo hmmm... now that I think about it, I'd go with the list. A unique_ptr prevents copying anyway. If you need to copy a lot, I'd go with a shared_ptr instead of the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler synthesized destructor is not going to delete dynamically allocated lists you put in your map, so you have to do it yourself. In this case you can just iterate through your map and delete the `second` member of each element:

```
EarleyParser::~EarleyParser() {
  for ( productionHashTable::iterator i = earlyHashTable.begin(); i != earlyHashTable.end(); ++i )
    delete i->second;
}
```

A better approach would be to put lists in your map rather than pointers to lists. In that case the compiler would automatically take care of destruction, as in:

```
typedef unordered_map< string, list<Production> > productionHashTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Unordered_map's destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/~unordered_map) actually calls the destructors of the object it has, which means that the destructor's of the `list`s will be called. 
[The destructor of std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/~list) has this note:

> Note, that if the elements are pointers, the pointed-to objects are not destroyed.

So this means, you will have to clear that memory yourself. Yes, going through the container and deleting elements 1by1 is fine. As other answerers mentioned, holding pointers like this is not a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a raw pointer to the `std::list` you'll have to delete it yourself either during the lifecycle of the map or when you clean up the `EarleyParser` object in its destructor.

You could use something like this in your destructor:

```
for ( auto it = productionHashTable.begin();
      it != productionHashTable.end(); ++it )
{ 
    delete it->second;
}
productionHashTable.clear()
```

Note that the last line isn't strictly necessary as it will be cleared anyway as the `EarleyParser` object is destructed but clearly you mustn't use the values in the map after you've deleted them!

Comment: The loop body is wrong: the `it` iterator should be used; whichever iterator is used should be dereferenced; second is a data member and not a member function.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti: Thanks, I wrote it originally as a `while ( ! productionHashTable.empty() )` loop - and then realised I wasn't erasing anything!